# TeamCity with Github

Tags: version-control

I downloaded TeamCity 5 and I can see the option for Git under "Edit VCS Root". I have supplied the Clone Url, Branch

Authentication Method: Default Private Key

But when I test the connection I get the following error:

The connection test failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: github.com. RSA key fingerprint i

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below that there is a line that says:

**Known Hosts Database:**

Check the box next to that that says:

**Do not check**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to connect over HTTP using authentication method "Password" with credentials you use at login page (email/password) instead of specifying SSH key.